# How do I address the screen on a linux terminal?

Tags: c++, linux, terminal

I am teaching myself C++ and currently run the latest Fedora.

On a Windows command prompt you can address the screen location.
I am led to the believe that a Linux command terminal works, effectively, like characters printed to a piece of paper. i.e. You can't go "up" from where you are.

However, when you install in Linux, there is a progress bar (in text) which doesn't appear to print a new line each time with the increase of progress.
Also, take for example raspbi-config in which you can tab/arrow up and down a "menu" and select "OK" and "Cancel" etc.

How does one achieve this?
Can this then be used to do simple text graphics applications in Linux like one can do under Windows?

Any help would be appreciated.

Uberlinc.

Coding in C++.
General non-gui apps which simply "cout" to the stdout.
Only found one or two examples which show a progress bar that prints out to the same line, but are not clear to me.

Comment: Did you try simply writing 1 character at a time, like `*`, and then `sleep()`ing for a second, before writing the next character? There's your progressbar.

Comment: curses or ncurses

Comment: There is nothing in C++ that'll help you with this so what pm100 says is the answer.

Comment: Your objective depends 100% on the capabilities of the terminal or console.  There is no single standard among all the terminals and console (emulators).  Some terminals are character only (teletype), some can do simple cursor position (VT52/VT100), others can do full graphics (console emulators).  Basically the C++ output sends stuff to the terminal or console and that's it.  Read up on ANSI Terminal Escape Sequences.  If you want better output graphics, build a GUI Framework or Windowing program, not a console based program.

Comment: I am able to run Tetris (called "Bastet") on Xfce Fedora 36.
(I'd post a screenshot in here if I could. How?)
It works like any other text based graphics screen.
This.
This is the sort of thing I'm trying to achieve.

Can a linux expert tell me where to start?

I'm not sure what the standard Xfce terminal is re: curses or ncurses.

@SamVarshavchik - You're completely missing what I'm asking, sorry.

Comment: bastet uses ncusrses. ncurses is well documented, I learned its API, by reading its documentation, several years ago. Happy reading.

Comment: Okay, thank you all.
I've now worked out what @pm100 was trying to say by "curses or ncurses" and I'm now watching tutorials about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a basic level, there are two things that enable these kinds of things on a Linux (or other POSIX) terminal: ASCII control characters and ANSI escape codes.

For a simple progress bar, it's enough to know how wide the screen is and to have a way to get back to the beginning of the current terminal line. This can be one by reading the environment variable `$COLUMNS` with `getenv` and by printing the ASCII control character `\r`. A very bare-bones and unbeautified example is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
  // Default screen width
  int width = 80;

  // Get screenwidth from environment
  char const *envwidth = getenv("COLUMNS");
  if(envwidth != nullptr) {
    std::istringstream(envwidth) >> width;
  }

  // save some space for numeric display
  width -= 10;
  
  for(int i = 1; i < width; ++i) {
    std::cout
          << '\r'                          // go back to start of line 
          << std::string(i, '.')           // progress bar
          << std::string(width  - i, ' ')  // padding
          << "| " << i << '/' << width     // numeric display
          << std::flush;                   // make the progress bar instantly visible

    // pretend to work
    usleep(100000);
  }
}
```

For more involved terminal "graphics,", there are [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). These allow you to set foreground and background color, move around on the screen at will, and a few other things, by printing special character sequences to stdout. For example,

```
std::cout << "\x1b[10;20HHello, world." << std::flush;
```

will print `Hello, world.` at position 10, 20 on the screen.

There is also the `ncurses` library that provides more high-level terminal UI functionality (windows, dialogs, that sort of thing). They use ANSI escape codes under the hood, but it's normally nicer to use that than to roll your own UI framework.

Comment: Wonderful!
That's a *great* start!
Thank you!

I will take your link on ANSI escape codes to see if this leads me to where I'm headed.

This was a good, practical and on-the-money response!
I thank you!

Comment: @Lincoln You should mark Wintermute's answer as the solution.